# How to set a dynamic number of threadCounter variables?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm not really into multithreading so probably the question is stupid but it seems I cannot find a way to solve this problem (especially because I'm using C# and I've been using it for a month).

I have a dynamic number of directories (I got it from a query in the DB). Inside those queries there are a certain amount of files.

For each directory I need to use a method to transfer these files using FTP in a cuncurrent way because I have basically no limit in FTP max connections (not my word, it's written in the specifics).

But I still need to control the max amount of files transfered per directory. So I need to count the files I'm transfering (increment/decrement).

How could I do it? Should I use something like an array and use the *Monitor* class?

Edit: Framework **3.5**

Comment: What is the thread granularity? One thread per file being uploaded or one thread per directory?

Comment: What is your framework target? are you using `4.0`?

Comment: @Unsliced: N Thread per directory. For each directory I have to transfer more file at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Semaphore` class to throttle the number of concurrent files per directory. You would probably want to have one semaphore per directory so that the number of FTP uploads per directory can be controlled independently.

```
public class Example
{
  public void ProcessAllFilesAsync()
  {
    var semaphores = new Dictionary<string, Semaphore>();
    foreach (string filePath in GetFiles())
    {
      string filePathCapture = filePath; // Needed to perform the closure correctly.
      string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
      if (!semaphores.ContainsKey(directoryPath))
      {
        int allowed = NUM_OF_CONCURRENT_OPERATIONS;
        semaphores.Add(directoryPath, new Semaphore(allowed, allowed));
      }
      var semaphore = semaphores[directoryPath];
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        (state) =>
        {
          semaphore.WaitOne();
          try
          {
            DoFtpOperation(filePathCapture);
          }
          finally
          {
            semaphore.Release();
          }
        }, null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I'm working on 3.5. SemaphoreSlim is a 4 feature. And it looks actually like a good feature.

Comment: @Dierre: It's a lambda expression. `state` is a parameter to the delegate (formed by a lamda expression) which I have completely ignored. Also note that this solution can block (via `WaitOne`) a `ThreadPool` thread which I typically advise against, but it will not hurt anything in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allDirectories = db.GetAllDirectories();
foreach(var directoryPath in allDirectories)
{
    DirectoryInfo directories = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
    //Loop through every file in that Directory
    foreach(var fileInDir in directories.GetFiles()) {
        //Check if we have reached our max limit
        if (numberFTPConnections == MAXFTPCONNECTIONS){
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        //code to copy to FTP
        //This can be Aync, when then transfer is completed
        //decrement the numberFTPConnections so then next file can be transfered.
     }
 }
```

You can try something along the lines above. Note that It's just the basic logic and there are proberly better ways to do this.

Comment: nope, I need to set a counter for each directory to count how many files I'm moving cuncurrently PER directory.